# Converting a jar file to exe file

Tags: java, python, integration, executable-jar

**Setup**

- I am running on windows 10
- Have python 3.6 and Java 8

**description**

I have a Java program which calls and passes an argument to a python program and then receives its output using system commands and cmd.

**Question**

How do I convert it into a single exe file that is the user can run it without installing java(jdk or jre)  and python.

Both are a part of my system variable

Thank you

Comment: How do **you** think this could be done?  Please show (at least) some attempts to solve your problem as explained in [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *"How do I convert it into an single exe file that is the user can run it without installing java(jdk or jre) and python"* - You can't - or more precisely - you write in a language which can produce a native executable, like C. A "broader" solution is to "embed" the Java JRE and JRE, but this is going to require you app to require an installer to copy all these resources, so it kind of defeats the purpose

Answer (score 1):

You can use launch4j application which can convert your jar to an .exe file.

Refer to this: https://www.programcreek.com/2009/05/convert-java-jar-file-to-exe/

Answer (score 0):

1. Use pyinstaller to package the python file in a exe.
2. Then in the java program replace xyz.py with xyz.exe
3. Use JarToExe to convert the jar into a Windows .exe file.

This way you would have two exe files but the user would not need to install java or python